# SimpleDateFormat parsing date with 'Z' literal

Tags: java, datetime, parsing, timezone, simpledateformat

I am trying to parse a date that looks like this:

> 2010-04-05T17:16:00Z

This is a valid date per http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt. The 'Z' literal (quote) "*imply that UTC is the preferred reference point for the specified time.*"

If I try to parse it using SimpleDateFormat and this pattern:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss
```

it will be parsed as a Mon Apr 05 17:16:00 EDT 2010

`SimpleDateFormat` is unable to parse the string with these patterns:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ
```

I can explicitly set the *TimeZone* to use on the `SimpleDateFormat` to get the expected output, but I don't think that should be necessary. Is there something I am missing? Is there an alternative date parser?

Comment: The 'Z' suffix in the time stamp should not be confused with the Z or z in the pattern. In java 7 you can parse an ISO8601 suffix with SimpleDateFormat using the 'X' pattern letter.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: [`'Z'` is not the same as `Z`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67953075/10819573)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In the pattern, the inclusion of a 'z' date-time component indicates that timezone format needs to conform to the [General time zone](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#timezone) "standard", examples of which are `Pacific Standard Time; PST; GMT-08:00`.

A 'Z' indicates that the timezone conforms to the [RFC 822 time zone](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#rfc822timezone) standard, e.g. `-0800`.

I think you need a DatatypeConverter ...

```
@Test
public void testTimezoneIsGreenwichMeanTime() throws ParseException {
    final Calendar calendar = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime("2010-04-05T17:16:00Z");
    TestCase.assertEquals("gotten timezone", "GMT+00:00", calendar.getTimeZone().getID());
}
```

Comment: yes, I understand that. The z/Z permutations were just me seeing if anything would stick. It still remains that my date is valid and there should be a valid pattern to parse it.

Comment: I was struggling to remember the class `DatatypeConverter` which a colleague showed me only recently.

Comment: Also see previous http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date answer

Comment: Thanks, I haven't seen this class before. It also seems there is finally a BASE64 en/decoder in the standard jdk classes :)

Comment: upgrade to java 7 (at least) and you will able to parsed

Comment: The third answer with the 'X' in the format string is the  most correct/up to date.

Comment: It works even in Java 6.

Answer (score 70):

The date you are parsing is in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

In Java 7 the pattern to read and apply the timezone suffix should read `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX`

Comment: This should have been the correct answer instead of accepted answer.

Comment: Also, if you want to parse the minutes in the timezone, simply add a second or third `X`: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXX` or `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX`. More details see [SimpleDateFormat - ISO 8601 Time zone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#iso8601timezone).

Comment: This should be the most pertinent answer than any other highly voted answers for the question

Answer (score 65):

Java doesn't parse ISO dates correctly.

Similar to McKenzie's answer.

Just fix the `Z` before parsing.

Code

```java
String string = "2013-03-05T18:05:05.000Z";
String defaultTimezone = TimeZone.getDefault().getID();
Date date = (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")).parse(string.replaceAll("Z$", "+0000"));

System.out.println("string: " + string);
System.out.println("defaultTimezone: " + defaultTimezone);
System.out.println("date: " + (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")).format(date));
```

Result

```
string: 2013-03-05T18:05:05.000Z
defaultTimezone: America/New_York
date: 2013-03-05T13:05:05.000-0500
```

Comment: Java 7 added pattern letter X to parse ISO dates.

Comment: "Java doesn't parse ISO dates correctly." -- Well, old Java does not. However, new Java does (Java 8 and later). See the new [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework.

Comment: Unfortunately a lot of us have to support older Java, such as Android phones pre-Android 7. (The Z pattern letter throws an exception on Android 6.)

Answer (score 45):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.parse ( "2010-04-05T17:16:00Z" )
```

---

## ISO 8601 Standard

Your String complies with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard (of which the mentioned [RFC 3339](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt) is a profile).

## Avoid java.util.Date

The java.util.Date and .Calendar classes bundled with Java are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them.

Instead use either the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library or the new java.time package in Java 8. Both use ISO 8601 as their defaults for parsing and generating string representations of date-time values.

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later supplants the troublesome old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes. The new classes are inspired by the highly successful [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) framework, intended as its successor, similar in concept but re-architected. Defined by [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). Extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. See the [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

The `Instant` class in java.time represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) time zone.

The `Z` at the end of your input string means `Zulu` which stands for `UTC`. Such a string can be directly parsed by the `Instant` class, with no need to specify a formatter.

```
String input = "2010-04-05T17:16:00Z";
Instant instant = Instant.parse ( input );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "instant: " + instant );
```

> instant: 2010-04-05T17:16:00Z

From there you can apply a time zone ([`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html)) to adjust this [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) into a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). Search Stack Overflow for discussion and examples.

If you must use a [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object, you can convert by calling the new conversion methods added to the old classes such as the static method [`java.util.Date.from( Instant )`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#from-java.time.Instant-).

```
java.util.Date date = java.util.Date.from( instant );
```

## Joda-Time

Example in Joda-Time 2.5.

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" ):
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( "2010-04-05T17:16:00Z", timeZone );
```

Convert to UTC.

```
DateTime dateTimeUtc = dateTime.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );
```

Convert to a java.util.Date if necessary.

```
java.util.Date date = dateTime.toDate();
```

Comment: Please mind this article by Stephen Colebourne: [Why JSR-310 isn't Joda-Time](http://blog.joda.org/2009/11/why-jsr-310-isn-joda-time_4941.html)

Answer (score 26):

According to last row on the *[Date and Time Patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#iso8601timezone)* table of the [Java 7 API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/text/DateFormat.html)

X   Time zone   ISO 8601 time zone  -08; -0800; -08:00

For ISO 8601 time zone you should use:

- X for (-08 or Z),
- XX for (-0800 or Z),
- XXX for (-08:00 or Z);

so to parse your "2010-04-05T17:16:00Z" you can use either
 ***"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX" or "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXX" or "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"*** .

```
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX").parse("2010-04-05T17:16:00Z"));
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXX").parse("2010-04-05T17:16:00Z"));
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX").parse("2010-04-05T17:16:00Z"));
```

will correctly print out 'Mon Apr 05 13:16:00 EDT 2010'

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, because it shows how to parse the date string using SimpleDateFormat like the question asked.

Answer (score 8):

The 'X' only works if partial seconds are not present: i.e. SimpleDateFormat pattern of

"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX"

Will correctly parse

"2008-01-31T00:00:00Z"

but

"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SX"

Will NOT parse

"2008-01-31T00:00:00.000Z"

Sad but true, a date-time with partial seconds does not appear to be a valid ISO date: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: This is terribly annoying.

Comment: Quote from referenced wiki page: "Decimal fractions may be added to any of the three time elements. [...] There is no limit on the number of decimal places for the decimal fraction. However, the number of decimal places needs to be agreed to by the communicating parties."
The "Z" is an independent notion for time zones.
So partial seconds ARE valid ISO dates. 
It would be nice to parse. (Maybe it is not a "Simple Date Format"? ;) )

Answer (score 7):

Under Java 8 use the predefined DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME

```
 DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME;
 ZonedDateTime result = ZonedDateTime.parse("2010-04-05T17:16:00Z", formatter);
```

I guess its the easiest way

Answer (score 4):

The time zone should be something like "GMT+00:00" or 0000 in order to be properly parsed by the SimpleDateFormat - you can replace Z with this construction.

Answer (score 4):

Since java 8 just use `ZonedDateTime.parse("2010-04-05T17:16:00Z")`

Answer (score 2):

The restlet project includes an InternetDateFormat class that can parse RFC 3339 dates.

[Restlet InternetDateFormat](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/snapshot/android/engine/org/restlet/engine/util/InternetDateFormat.html)

Though, you might just want to replace the trailing 'Z' with "UTC" before you parse it.

Comment: Restlet InternetDateFormat worked well for me

Answer (score 2):

I provide another answer that I found by `api-client-library` by Google

```
try {
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parseRfc3339(date);
    dateTime = new DateTime(new Date(dateTime.getValue()), TimeZone.getDefault());
    long timestamp = dateTime.getValue();  // get date in timestamp
    int timeZone = dateTime.getTimeZoneShift();  // get timezone offset
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Installation guide,
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/setup#download

Here is API reference,
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/util/DateTime

Source code of `DateTime` Class,
https://github.com/google/google-http-java-client/blob/master/google-http-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/util/DateTime.java

`DateTime` unit tests,
https://github.com/google/google-http-java-client/blob/master/google-http-client/src/test/java/com/google/api/client/util/DateTimeTest.java#L121

Answer (score 2):

With regards to JSR-310 another project of interest might be [threetenbp](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threetenbp).

> JSR-310 provides a new date and time library for Java SE 8. This project is the backport to Java SE 6 and 7.

In case you are working on an **Android** project you might want to checkout the [ThreeTenABP library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

```groovy
compile "com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:${version}"
```

> JSR-310 was included in Java 8 as the java.time.* package. It is a full replacement for the ailing Date and Calendar APIs in both Java and Android. JSR-310 was backported to Java 6 by its creator, Stephen Colebourne, from which this library is adapted.