# Java Date format of '2010-10-11T22:10:10.000Z'

Tags: java

What date format is '2010-10-11T22:10:10.000Z' ?

Comment: 02-04 21:05:28.106: WARN/System.err(2760): java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: 2010-05-14T01:29:30.000Z

Comment: If your question is directed toward actually parsing a date in that format, this is probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580925/simpledateformat-parsing-date-with-z-literal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's an [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date format.

If you're looking to actually parse a date in that format (your question doesn't really make your intentions clear), have a look at [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date) questions.

Comment: FYI, thIs ISO 8601 format is used by default for parsing and generating strings in both the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library and the new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) built into Java 8 and later.

Answer (score 2):

It is ISO 8601 format expressed in UTC (i.e. it is not carrying the timezone offset)

Answer (score 1):

Where did you get that string from? XML? Then use:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html

Or better: consider to use JAXB