# What is the technical term of the time format of this value "20150716203621.000Z"?

Tags: java, date, unix, formatting, timestamp

So I have a time value in the format "20150716203621.000Z", I retrieved from an LDAP server, however I am not sure what the format of this time is in? The ultimate goal is to be able to convert it to a Java.Util.Date Object. Does anyone know what the technical term of this format is? Thanks.

Comment: yyyyMMddHHmmss.zzz(Z)

Comment: Similar Question: [Java Date format of '2010-10-11T22:10:10.000Z'](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4900028/642706).

Answer (score 1):

It seems to refer to a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) object. The `Z` at the end refers to the timezone. See [simpledateformat parsing date with 'Z' literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580925/simpledateformat-parsing-date-with-z-literal).

Answer (score 1):

yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00.000Z

So 20150716203621.000Z is 2015.07.16. 20:36:21 and 000 is milliseconds.

Z means UTC timezone.

Answer (score 1):

This is the standard date/time format as specified in [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339), a profile of [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

From RFC :

```
  date-fullyear   = 4DIGIT
  date-month      = 2DIGIT  ; 01-12
  date-mday       = 2DIGIT  ; 01-28, 01-29, 01-30, 01-31 based on
                             ; month/year
  time-hour       = 2DIGIT  ; 00-23
  time-minute     = 2DIGIT  ; 00-59
  time-second     = 2DIGIT  ; 00-58, 00-59, 00-60 based on leap second
                             ; rules
  time-secfrac    = "." 1*DIGIT
  time-numoffset  = ("+" / "-") time-hour ":" time-minute
  time-offset     = "Z" / time-numoffset
```

Comment: The example `20150716203621.000Z` shown in the Question is the "basic" version of this format. The expanded version is easier to read: `2015-07-T16:20:36.21.000Z` with a `T` separating the date portion from time-of-day portion. You may trade the `T` for a SPACE for further readability but not recommended for data exchange.