# JSON data to datetime Android

Tags: java, android, json, datetime

i want ask about how i can change date format from data JSON?
 
example the result from JSON is : Thu, 19 Jul 2012 23:28:44 +0000 --> i put that result into string
and i want change that into : datetime with my timezone --> GMT +07:00

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
    // Sat, 23 Jun 2012 00:00:00 +0000
    String date = "Sat, 23 Jun 2012 00:00:00 +0000";
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");

        SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm");

       date = df2.format(format.parse(str));

    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

CHeck this link if it helps you

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2581073/1441666

Comment: okay thx but i have another question, "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z" , z var i get is GMT +7 , but how i can change it into GMT +9?

Answer (score 1):

```
Date d = new Date("Thu, 19 Jul 2012 23:28:44 +0000");
SimpleDateFormat frmt = new SimpleDateFormat ("format");

frmt.setTimeZone(zone);// you need to know the zone here..
frmt.format(d);
```

hope it works..

Answer (score 0):

Try to parse date with a simpleDateFormat and change your timezone.

Comment: silly me. apparently the format parsing changes the date to your time zone. nirali's answer should help you.