# Windows Azure Date Format to Java Date

Tags: java, json, datetime, azure

I'm retrieving JSON from Azure and receive the date as `1900-01-01T16:00:00.000Z` for example. Now this part of a JSONObject, but how do I correctly parse this into the Java date format?

Thanks for any ideas

Comment: Looks like ISO 8601 format.  Use javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime - See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the date as a String from the Json then parsed it using [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("/*Look at the API for the format*/");
Date jsonDate= sdf.parse(/*Date as String from your JSON*/);
```

To find the correct format you can have a look to this question [simpledateformat parsing date with 'Z' literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580925/simpledateformat-parsing-date-with-z-literal).