# How to convert Google Drive's Date format in java?

Tags: java, date

This is what I tried so far but is not working:
This is the format of the date return by the Drive api's json response
2014-04-29T17:58:02.437Z

```
final SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz");
System.out.println(df.parse("2014-04-29T17:58:02.437Z"));
```

What is the correct way to convert it?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580925/simpledateformat-parsing-date-with-z-literal)

Comment: In addition to the answers above it's worth noting that (if it's an option for you) Java 8's new Date/Time API handles ISO-8601 natively.

Answer (score 0):

Quick suggestion for:

```
final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println(sdf.parse("2014-04-29T17:58:02.437Z"));
```

As you see, Z is simply set by GMT, while you was not parsing 437 milliseconds.

Works for me, just tried it out!