# Java parsing date

Tags: date, groovy

Hello i am currently looking for parsing a date in groovy/java

the format is "June 13 2003" ( not so exotic !!! )

A simple look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html give me some clues

> Month: If the number of pattern letters is 3 or more, the month is interpreted as text; otherwise, it is interpreted as a number.
>
> Year : if the number of pattern letters is more than 2, the year is interpreted literally

So i would guess that "MMMM d yyyy" is fine
But even trying other patterns : "MMM d yyyy","M d yyyy","MMM dd yyyy", none of them works .......

```
    Date dateParsed = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d yyyy").parse("June 13 2003")
    println dateParsed
```

gives me an exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "June 13 2003"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unparseable date: "Fri Oct 10 23:11:07 IST 2014" (at offset 20)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27375489/unparseable-date-fri-oct-10-231107-ist-2014-at-offset-20)

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your formats should work, the problem might be locale - if your system is not in english locale by default, it tries to parse your local month names, instead of the english variants.

Try

```
new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd yyyy", java.util.Locale.ENGLISH)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        Date dateParsed = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d yyyy").parse("June 13 2003");
        System.out.println(dateParsed);
    }
}
```

This works fine for me. Prints Fri Jun 13 00:00:00 EEST 2003

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse( 
    "June 13 2003" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMMM d uuuu" )
                     .withLocale( Locale.US )
)
```

## java.time

The modern way is with the java.time classes.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

Use `DateTimeFormatter` to parse a string that is not in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The crucial part is to specify a `Locale` to determine the human language to use in translating the name of month, English is this case.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMMM d uuuu" ) ;
f = f.withLocale( Locale.UK );  // Or Locale.US, or Locale.ENGLISH, or Locale.CANADA_FRENCH, whatever matches your inputs.
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "June 13 2003" , f ) ;
```

> 2003-06-13

[See code in action, in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/oy7b91).

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).