# Android SimpleDateFormat Unparsable Date

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat, parse-error

i got this Date String for example:

```
Wed, 19 Oct 2016 12:00 PM CEST
```

now i am trying to convert it to a Calendar with the help of the SimpleDateFormat

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy hh:m a zzz", Locale.US);
```

And when i try to parse it i get the following error:

```
Unparseable date: "Wed, 19 Oct 2016 12:00 PM CEST" (at offset 26)
```

I appreciate every help!

**Edit:**

Full parsing code:

```
@Override
public WeatherData parseCurrentWeatherData(String jsonString) {

    WeatherData weatherData = new WeatherData();

    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);

        JSONObject mainObj = obj.getJSONObject("query").getJSONObject("results").getJSONObject("channel");

        JSONObject condition = mainObj.getJSONObject("item").getJSONObject("condition");

        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:m a z", Locale.US);
        cal.setTime(sdf.parse(condition.getString("date")));

        weatherData.setCalendar(cal);

    } catch(JSONException | ParseException ex) {
        Log.e("DataFetcher", ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    return weatherData;
}
```

**Solution:**

It looks like Android can't parse some timezones. Thanks to @Burhanuddin Rashid for this approach.

```
String strDate = condition.getString("date").replace("CEST", "GMT+0200");
```

Solution here: [Unparseable date: "Fri Oct 10 23:11:07 IST 2014" (at offset 20)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27375489/unparseable-date-fri-oct-10-231107-ist-2014-at-offset-20)

Comment: Your code works well.

Comment: But why do i get a parse error in my environment then?

Comment: Can you post your full parsing code?

Comment: i updated my question @0riginal

Comment: Just try printing condition.getString("date") to check whether you are getting the right string

Comment: i checked this already, and yes i got the right string @Muzy

Comment: when im logging the string im getting this line: "D/YahooWeatherDataParser: Wed, 19 Oct 2016 12:00 PM CEST" - so it's allright

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add extra d in it like this :

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:m a zzz", Locale.US);
    sdf.setLenient(true);
```

Comment: Try setting this `sdf.setLenient(true);`

Comment: Try removing comma(,) from "EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:m a zzz" and from `condition.getString("date")` from this replacce comma(,) with nothing like this `condition.getString("date").replace(",","")`

Comment: Still got the error "Unparseable date: "Wed 19 Oct 2016 01:00 PM CEST" (at offset 25)"

Comment: i think maybe it has to do with the "CEST" because it always throws the error at the offset position from CEST?

Comment: Its seems IST issue you can refer this it might help :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27375489/unparseable-date-fri-oct-10-231107-ist-2014-at-offset-20

Answer (score 2):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String dateString = "Wed, 19 Oct 2016 12:00 PM CEST";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy hh:m a zzz", Locale.US);
    Date date = sdf.parse(dateString);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    System.out.println(calendar);
  }
```

The same thing worked for me.

**Make sure all the imports are correct**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition.getString("date") and  the format in the "SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:m a z", Locale.US);" doesn't match.

Comment: there it is @Çağatay Karslı