# How to Parse Date in ISO format in Java?

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat

I am receiving `iso` format date in `Java`. How can I parse it to get `MM` and `DD`.

Date in iso format:`2015-08-10T21:00:00.090Z`

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: Do you mean *ISO* format?

Comment: @AndyTurner Yes, It was typo mistake

Comment: Try this page. Similar question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580925/simpledateformat-parsing-date-with-z-literal?rq=1

Comment: If you use Java 8, you could do it easily with: `ZonedDateTime date = ZonedDateTime.parse("2015-08-10T21:00:00.090Z", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some references

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault(), Locale.getDefault()) ;
SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.getDefault());
try {
        Date date = dateformat.parse("2015-08-10T21:00:00.090Z");
        cal.setTime(date);
        String result = new SimpleDateFormat("MM dd", Locale.getDefault()).format(cal.getTime());
        System.out.println(result);

} catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

## java.time

The other answer uses troublesome old date-time classes now supplanted by the java.time classes.

The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing and generating Strings that represent date-time values.

An [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html)  represents a moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2015-08-10T21:00:00.090Z" );
```

Adjust into the time zone through which you want to see this moment.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

You can interrogate for month and day-of-month.

```
int month = zdt.getMonthValue();
int dayOfMonth = zdt.getDayOfMonth();
```