# get SimpleDateFormat return wrong answer

Tags: java, timestamp, simpledateformat

I need to convert timestamp string to long.
Here is my input string:

```
2016-08-10T11:24:57.182+0300
```

here is code witch I am trying to use for converting:

```
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.sssZ");
        try {
            Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(timestamp);

            long time = date.getTime();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

result: `1470817622000`

but when i check this long time [here](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/java/date2millis.htm), it returns me this string:

```
10 august 2016 8:27:02 GMT
```

but this is different from the input string.
any idea why it happens and how to fix this?

Comment: What do you mean different from the input string? Your input is GMT+0300.

Comment: Whats the java version you are using? The `Z` is only supported from java-7 upwards. [also see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580925/simpledateformat-parsing-date-with-z-literal)

Comment: @KevinEsche  Refer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html We can use Z in Java 6 also.

Comment: @Andriy Antonov: You are getting the correct output 10 august 2016 8:27:02 GMT ~= 2016-08-10T11:24:57.182+0300 (I used equivalent sign since there is few minutes of difference)

Comment: @Unknown, yep, looks like. but i need to convert that time according with the timezone